# python - use a function to draw multiple plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm new to python. I'm trying to run the following code to simulate the sales of a stand. The code uses calculateTips, calculateProfit functions to predict the tips and profit of sales based on their chance of happening. The summariseData function is used to mainly plot the histogram of it's input data. summariseData is used about 5 times in the code, so we are supposed to have 5 different plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np  
import pandas as pd  
import  numpy.random as nr  

def summariseData(distribution, name = 'distribution name'):
    ser = pd.Series(distribution)
    plt.figure()
    plt.hist(ser, bins = 120)
    plt.title('Frequency distribution of ' + name)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.show()
    print('')
    out = ser.describe()
    ##plt.show(block = True)
    return out

def calculateProfit(num):
    profit = nr.uniform(size = num)
    out = [5 if x < 0.3 else (3.5 if x < 0.6 else 4) for x in profit]
    return out

def calculateTips(num):
    tips = nr.uniform(size = num)
    out = [0 if x < 0.5 else (0.25 if x < 0.7 
                  else (1 if x < 0.9 else 2)) for x in tips]
    return  out

def finalSimulation(num, mean = 600, std = 30):  

    arrival = nr.normal(loc = mean, size = num, scale = std)

    profit = calculateProfit(num)
    print(summariseData(profit, name = 'profit per arrival'))
    totalProfit = arrival * profit 
    print(summariseData(totalProfit, name = 'total profit per day'))

    tip = calculateTips(num)
    print(summariseData(tip, name = 'tips per arrivals'))
    totalTip = arrival * tip
    print(summariseData(totalTip, name = 'total tips per day'))

    totalGain = totalProfit + totalTip
    return summariseData(totalGain, name = 'net gain per day')

if __name__ == "__main__" : 
        finalSimulation(100000)
```

when I run the code in Eclipse, the first plot appears. But, in order to see the next plot, I have to close the current plot ( which is shown on the screen).

Here's the Problem: when I run the code, I want plots to show up in different figures (I want to see them all together). Not that to close one of them to see the next one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so to do this create a new figure for each plot:

```
plt.figure(1)
```

and then all your normal attributes, ylabel, xlabel, etc.
then for each

```
plt.hist(normal args)
```

Finally, once you have created figures for each and plotted what you want to them, finally:

```
plt.show()
```

will display all the figures.

So in short, make sure that you pass a new number to your plt.figure() and put plt.show() outside of all your loops and functions.

For example:

```
def plot(ser, fig_num):
    plt.figure(fig_num)
    plt.hist(ser)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i don't know where to place plt.show()?  i tried to put it at the end of the code, but nothing changed. and now i added a fig_num to the summariseData. so it looks like your example.

Comment: I would put it in __main__, so it runs last.  are you giving a new number to each figure?

Comment: yeas, the code now looks like this :   def summariseData(distribution, figure_number, name = 'distribution name'): plt.figure(figure_number) 
and then the rest of the code.

Comment: and for each time the function is run, the figure_number changes?  If you don't want to pass anything in, just create a counter in the function that increments when the function has run and use that number.